# Why is Use of an unassigned local variable allowed here?

Tags: c#, .net

Normally the compiler forbids any use of unassigned local variables, but not in the following case. Why?

```
private void Main()
{
    // This local variable is unassigned.
    string myVar;
    
    try
    {
        // The Throw() method prevents the assignment from happening...
        myVar = Throw();
    }
    finally
    {
        // ... so myVar is still unassigned.
    }

    // Here we use myVar, which is unassigned, and the compiler is not complaining.
    if (myVar.Equals("Something"))
    {
        // ...
    }
}

private string Throw()
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: Along with the answer you may note that using a `try` without a `catch` is meaningless. Technically, a `try` with only a `finally` clause would amount to the same code being executed without the `try` or `finally`. In other words, you should put this question in a “realistic” context. If you add the `catch` as it “should” be… then the compiler WILL complain about the possible unassigned variable.

Comment: @JohnG I have to disagree with your assertion that a `try` without a `catch` is meaningless. There are scenarios where you would use `try` just with `finally`, because in those scenarios ensuring something happens regardless of the success of the `try` is what you want to do, rather than handling the error itself.

Comment: @JohnG [Here](https://rextester.com/NOUHY92391) is an example of when I might use a `try` with only a `finally` block.

Comment: @Llama… thanks for the link to an example. I will agree somewhat to what you are saying and yes in the example you linked to, it clearly shows that my assumption that “both” sections would execute is proved to be wrong as the example shows that “without” the `try` and `finally` clause then the finally code would never get executed. Thank you for clarifying this for me. I guess I am old in my ways and would never use a try without a catch. Live and learn… thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception in the example is not caught by `Main()`. Therefore, if the exception is thrown, the code after the `finally` block is unreachable, and if the exception is not thrown, the assignment occurs. That's why in any case a use of an unassigned variable cannot happen. And since it cannot happen, the compiler doesn't report it.

Comment: Indeed. Either `myVar = Throw();` successfully instantiates `myVar` or an exception is thrown. In the latter case, `myVar.Equals` will never be reached.

Comment: I think it has something to do with code paths/stack/jumps. If you add a `catch` to the try function then it will give you the unused variable error since the possibility of an empty happens.